Как мне сделать текст(он изначально дан) фоном в винформс ,чтобы поверх него можно было печатать?
Хочу сделать приложение для обучения слепой печати, но из-за нехватки опыта не могу разобраться как сделать текст в текстбоксе серым, чтобы он был фоном ( пример, когда просят что-то ввести), но не пропадал после "клика" или когда пользователь начинал печатать, т.е. пользователь печатал поверх этого текста. Прошу объясните как это сделать на си шарпе. В интернете нет объяснения:(

даже если и можно это сделать, то текст наложенный на текст создаст артефакты субпиксельного антиалиасинга, и наверное стоит пересмотреть концепцию приложения; переопределить поведение текст-бокса можно, но это сложно, и понятное дело нужно будет переопределять поведение рендера, и тут вы и упрётесь в проблему артефактов - это всё будет выглядеть "сильно не очень"; откройте пайнт и напечатайте там строку, а затем поверх этой строки напечатайте ещё строку - ужас получите

всё то что связано с графикой [особенно с двумерной] - обычно легко проверяется на любых приспособленных для этого приложениях, и это я всего лишь про то, что обычно нет смысла программировать что либо графическое, пока вы не получите годный графический оригинал-макет; очевидно здесь то, что на выходе любого гуя (gui - graphical user interface) - некий графический контекст, так вот прежде чем программировать - соберите где либо этот графический контекст и посмотрите что получится; пересобирать графоний в том же пайнте сильно проще, чем его программировать [и тем более - перепрограммировать]
